# .htaccess dont let me load files

Tags: php, apache

Im using an htaccess to load my php files, and the mvc works good but I cannot load files like images, js, css, etc..

My folder structure its the same as Laravel and my .htaccess file is:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If i modify the code I can load the images and some differents roots but i cannot load the /

Any help its appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A good answer also includes an explanation, not just a code block. You've also completely missed the `?url=`-part.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I fixed my problem was replacing the code in the question for this one

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```